# I want to access the WebContent-Title from the velocity Template

Tags: liferay, web-content

Something like this

```
$Title.getData()
```

or

```
$title.getData()
```

don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$reserved-article-title`.

Also see this Liferay's [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMS+Internal+API) for complete reference.